# should I close a file in PHP's __destruct() method?

Tags: php, destructor, file-handling, fclose

In my script I need an  open stream to a CSV file and my application will read single, many or all of its lines depending on different request, and store them in an array!

when and if we reach to the point that all lines been read and stored, the scrip will close the file.

but also i've added the close file method into the class destructor

```
public function __destruct()
{
    fclose($this->handler)
}
```

I want to know if this is really necessary? or considering this is the end of lifecycle of my script, the file handler will be taken care by PHP's garbage collector and adding the above destruct method doesn't add any value?

Comment: Close the file as soon as you no longer need it.

Comment: when and if we reach to the point that all lines been read and stored, the scrip will close the file.

Comment: So what's the problem, exactly? Seems like you're trying to close the handler twice, why?

Comment: If it worked, select my answer as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I preffer to close the file when no more writing is need or in an exception:

```
try {
//write file
//close file after all reading operations has been done
} catch (Exception $e) {
 fclose($this->handler);
}
```

This is good as an emergency or an uncatched problem, because PHP will close the file after deleting the object. If not, PHP interpreter will free all resources, and in Files it will free the memory address and any pending writing won't be done.

Comment: So then closing a file in the destructor doesn't really add any value, right?

Comment: If you control the file operation inside a try/catch no. Otherwise it prevents file writing problems.